# Regex - matching characters in string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

So, I'm looking for a way to validate a string using the PHP `preg_match()` function.

The first character must be a letter and it must be either `J`, `R` or `P`.
The second character must be a letter.
Characters 3-8 must be a number.

Anyone have some guidance on how I can accomplish this?  Please and thank you.

Comment: you not tried anything yourself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for `/^[JRP][A-Z][0-9]{6}$/`?

**Autopsy:**

- `^` - the string MUST start here
- `[JRP]` - either of the characters "J", "R" or "P"
- `[A-Z]` - letters from A-Z (uppercase)
- `[0-9][6}` - digits from 0 to 9 matched exactly 6 times (so you get 8 characters in total)
- `$` - the string MUST end here

**Use in PHP:**

```
if (preg_match('/^[JRP][A-Z][0-9]{6}$/', $string)) {
    echo "Matches!";
}
```

If you want to search in a text you can skip out `^` and `$`:

```
if (preg_match_all('/[JRP][A-Z][0-9]{6}/', $string)) {
    echo "Matches!";
}
```

If you want it to match letters of lower case as well, you can just add `a-z` to the `[A-Z]` match as so: `[a-zA-Z]`.

Answer (score 1):

This should simply do the work

```
/^[JRP][A-Za-z]\d{6}$/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = 'JJ123456';

if (preg_match('/^J|R|P[a-zA-Z][0-9]{6}$/', $string))
{
    // Matched
}
else
{
    // Does not match
}
```

Comment: You are missing ' at the end of regex.

Comment: the brackets `(` `)` to group the result are not necessary. The OP only want to know if the check against the regex is `true` or `false`. And `{1}` is also unnecessary because `[0-9]` means already `one char`.

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER Thank you for the guidance!  Always learning :)

Comment: Np :-). But `J|R|P` you have to put in square brackets like `[J|R|P]` and you can strip the pipes `|`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$val = "JA1234";
var_dump(preg_match("/^[JRP][a-zA-Z][0-9]{6}$/", $val));
```

---

Where:

```
^ - place of a start of string
$ - place of the end of string
so whole string should be matched with reqular expression
[JRP] - one of the letter from the list
[a-zA-Z] - one letter
[0-9]{6} - digit should be repeated 6 times
```

Comment: Characters 3 TO 8 should be a number, not a number between 3 and 8 in length